# iPhone 4S dropped down the toilet

Tags: iphone, data-synchronization, data

I have dropped my iPhone down the toilet (it was in my back pocket) for some reason my new phone has not registered with iCloud and wouldn't load my old photos from the broken phone and they disappeared off of my iPad!

I know stupid I should of backed it up... the question is how do I get my photos back? It turns on and off by itself now so it really doesn't work, is there a way of getting the photos back? Shame because I lost all my sons baby photos :( thank you in advance

Comment: Do you have a computer you can use? You can create a local backup of your phone on a computer, then restore that back up to a new phone (this will sync all the photos and music etc. on the phone so long as you can unlock it)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different things to check:

1. Verify if there is an iCloud backup of the phone by going to `Settings > iCloud > Storage > Manage Storage`. Here you will see a section titled "Backups" which will show you if there was an iPhone backup.
2. Try signing into iCloud on the new phone to see if there is any chance the photos are actually on your iCloud Photo Stream but it's not showing up on your iPad for some unknown reason.
3. Wait a few days for the iPhone to dry out and see if you can download the photos from the phone via your computer.